# How can I achieve the "View slide-in" effect in react native?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am currently working on my very first react-native application and am wondering how that slide in effect of a new view can be achieved and where that "hidden" view should be placed.

My Application is currently build like this:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
 <View style={{flex:.8, justifyContent:'center'}}>
   .. some login Form
 </View>
 <View style={{flex:.2, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._toggleRegistryView}>
     <Text> or register here </Text>
   </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
</View>
```

As you can see in this basic code I want to slide-in the Registration View as soon as the touchable component is pressed.

Do I need to store the view "invisible" with a width of 0 and height of 100% on one side and then animate it to the full device width?

Right now I have no idea besides a whole new view render when the state changes

```
render(){
   return({this.state.view == 'login' ? <LoginView /> : <RegistryView />});
}
```

Unfortunately this triggers a "hard" view change and not a smooth right to left or left to right animation where the view slides in.

If my question was unclear please inform me - I'll gladly try to specify it :) Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split your application into multiple scenes (screens) and use the [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content) component to transition between the scenes.

Here is a [tutorial from the TaskRabbit blog](http://tech.taskrabbit.com/blog/2015/09/21/react-native-example-app/) to get you started.

Once you have you scenes set up, you can experiment with different [SceneConfigs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorSceneConfigs.js) for different types of transition animations.

Answer (score 0):

A transition from a page to another is nothing else but **navigation**.

In order to navigate from a page to another in React Native, you will want a **navigation library**.

The default Navigator component from React Native might work, but it's got a lot of limitations and issues, and the default solution most people turn to (and which after 3yrs of RN I strongly recommend), is [**React Navigation**](https://reactnavigation.org/). If you are using Expo, it also ships by default, so you can [jump right into it](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html), and define your screens like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginView,
  },
  Register: {
    screen: RegisterView,
  },
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

If not, [here's a quick start guid to using it outside of Expo](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html).